# Is there a python equivalent of gdaltindex?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, tiles, gdaltindex

I am using the following gdal shell command ([`gdaltindex`](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html)) to create a raster tile index from a directory of raster (tif) files.

```
find /path/to/raster/directory -name "*.tif" -exec gdaltindex tile-index.shp {} \;
```

Is there an open source Python approach that can produce the same raster tile index shapefile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dont't know, but it's easy to do with osgeo.gdal, [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) and [shapely box](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.geometry.box) ( `shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy, ccw=True)` = bounding box)¶

#### Original raster files

```
import os 
StartDir = "/Shared/scan_ign/68"    
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(StartDir):
    for fname in files:
       if fname.endswith(".tif"):
           print(fname,)

68_1.tif
68_2.tif
68_3.tif
68_4.tif
68_5.tif
68_6.tif
68_7.tif
68_8.tif
```

#### With gdalindex

```
gdaltindex index.shp *.tif
```

#### Control

```
import geopandas as gpd
index =  gpd.read_file('index.shp')
print index.head()
    location                geometry
0  68_1.tif  POLYGON ((226018.4754020752 58174.93482261647,...
1  68_2.tif  POLYGON ((234019.0396324735 58174.8250049785, ...
2  68_3.tif  POLYGON ((242020.0156871924 58175.55617328714,...
3  68_4.tif  POLYGON ((250020.4746237129 58176.34366682862,...
4  68_5.tif  POLYGON ((226019.5264973617 48175.2918232924, ...
```

#### With osgeo.gdal

```
from osgeo import gdal
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box
# compute the bounding box of a gdal raster file
def bounds_raster(path):
    raster = gdal.Open(path) 
    ulx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    lrx = ulx + (raster.RasterXSize * xres) 
    lry = uly + (raster.RasterYSize * yres)
    return box(lrx,lry,ulx,uly) 
# creation of the index file
 df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['location','geometry'])
 # iterate through multiple tif files in a folder
 for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(StartDir):
     for fname in files:
         if fname.endswith(".tif"):
              df = df.append({'location':fname, 'geometry': bounds( os.path.join(dir+"/", fname))},ignore_index=True)
 print df.head()
      location                  geometry
 0  68_1.tif  POLYGON ((226018.4754020752 48173.94230128427,...
 1  68_2.tif  POLYGON ((234019.0396324735 48173.84503544428,...
 2  68_3.tif  POLYGON ((242020.0156871924 48174.31088528392,...
 3  68_4.tif  POLYGON ((250020.4746237129 48174.72574336932,...
 4  68_5.tif  POLYGON ((226019.5264973617 38173.0677178388, ...
 # save resulting shapefile
 df.to_file("tile-index.shp")
```

#### As Spacedman points out, you can also use rasterio

```
 import rasterio
 df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['location','geometry'])
 for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(StartDir):
       for fname in files:
         if fname.endswith(".tif"):
            bounds =rasterio.open(os.path.join(dir+"/", fname)).bounds
            df = df.append({'location':fname, 'geometry': box(bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2], bounds[3])},ignore_index=True)
df.to_file("tile-index2.shp")
```

Comment: Is there a typo in line 2 of your bounds_raster function? `rast=gdal.Open(path)` then `raster.GetGeoTransform()`

Comment: The rasterio approach is particularly nice. Thanks to @Spacedman too. FYI, the indentation is off on that portion;)

Comment: Think I've fixed the indenting for you.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, `gdaltindex` returns a feature for each raster input, as a rectangular polygon of the bounds of each raster. I don't know of a ready plug-in solution for doing `gdaltindex` in pure python (as opposed to shelling out to run `gdaltindex`) and I'll assume you've searched for it. The parts to build a solution are available though.

You can use `rasterio` to read rasters and get the bounds:

```
>>> r = rasterio.open("mwi_lc_1990.tif")
>>> r.bounds
BoundingBox(left=454965.0, bottom=8094361.0, right=823965.0, top=8974795.0)
>>> r.bounds.left
454965.0
```

And then you can use the `fiona` package to create shapefiles.